# La mejor manera de recortar un input de bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, formularios

Tengo un form con este label y imput para añadir el valor

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
    </div>
```

Que genera esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero recorta el input, que no sea tan largo.
Según el manual de bootstrap, tengo que añadir un div con las columnas que quiero que ocupe, de esta forma:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Pero se desarma todo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como se haría y cuál es el problema?

Edit: Según lo que tengo descargado, la versión de bootstap es: Bootstrap v3.3.6

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap utilizas?

Comment: La versión Bootstrap v3.3.6. Gracias

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas otro css que esté interfiriendo? He puesto los dos trozos de tu código en este fiddle y se ve bien: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/d5gqzzqt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

esto no está bien:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

ya que no se lo deberías de aplicar a todo el contenedor de form-group y no solamente al input, para lo que tu buscas es así:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"/>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 4):

Debes poner tu `label` e `input` en una class `row`, para poder utilizar correctamente las columnas, a continuación te dejo un snipeed con un ejemplo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-xs-2" for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
      </div>
 </div>
```

> Puedes determinar que tamaño de columna ocupe el `label` o el `input`, cambiando
>   el `.col-xs-` entre 1 y 12, teniendo 12 como el tamaño máximo de una row. (los elementos si suman mas de 12 se ubicaron en dos filas)

Adicional:
[Aqui puedes ver para que tamaños es cada prefijo (xs - sm - md - lg)](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#grid-options)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)